# How to force EJB Scheduler in JBeret

Tags: wildfly, jberet

I'm implementing a Scheduler based in JBeret SchedulerTimer.

I had it working with the possibility of "Calendar-based Schedule" and "persistence" (EJB Timer), but currently the project has these features disabled reverting to Managed Scheduled Executor Service [Jberet scheduling type](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/269527).
Don't know what were the changes that made these features become disabled, but I need to activate them again.

Is there a way to force the project to use EJB timer?

The feature check is done [through rest Api,](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/commit/51091b4ccb26284193bba29e761b386fedb2a4fe) but it is not clear what to change to have EJB feature available

Answer (score 1):

Corrected the problem.

The [BatchRestService](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/commit/22696b71659fc8c0d05b496e6f4a5c5a8099ab1b) asks for supported features to jberet through the restApi
http://localhost:8080/project/api//schedules/features

The project needs to explicitly load the correct dependency, I had both jberet-scheduler-executor and jberet-scheduler-timer in the project's pom.xml, this caused some conflict and the executor was answering that it didn't support the Calendar and Persistence features.

I've used only the jberet-scheduler-timer dependency and it worked (removed the jberet-scheduler-executor)

Comment: You can see which scheduler is selected in [JobScheduler](https://github.com/jberet/jberet-schedule/blob/master/jberet-schedule-executor/src/main/java/org/jberet/schedule/JobScheduler.java#L86).If the scheduler EJB can be obtained via lookup, the scheduler based on EJB timer will be used; otherwise, it uses one based on scheduled executor.